# Is it possible to print emacs org mode without asterisks?

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to print without extra asterisks, looking more like an outline? I tried to print with `ps-print-customize` but that just added a gray hader.

---

**EDIT**

[Here](http://members.optusnet.com.au/~charles57/GTD/agenda_reformatting.html) there is a python script that does what I want. It prints the outline formatted. Would it be possible to write such a script with `elisp`?

Comment: I think Org has an option to export to ASCII, wouldn't that be something like what you want? (less decoration).

Comment: @wvxvw Almost, but it does not indent. Asterisks are not there, instead it inserted numbering but since it does not indent it is hard to read when printed.

Comment: With a later version of Org you can also export to texinfo and man pages. Man looks more structured and it doesn't have asterisks, but I can't figure how to load it into Emacs later (but it displays fine in shell).  Some info on how to seupt export dispatcher: http://orgmode.org/manual/Other-built_002din-back_002dends.html#Other-built_002din-back_002dends

Comment: Yup, that would be quite simple actually, but why not use it as is? You could use it with, for example, `shell-command` (bound to `M-!`). Another option would be to use Pymacs - a Python library which allows you to script Emacs in Python (depending on how much you want to invest into this effort, this might be a better options).